# What does 'ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)' mean

Tags: python

This is a task that collects data for 3 fundraising activities and presents it in a table, but I keep on getting this error. Can you identify what the error is?

```
def get_activityName(list12l):
  '''function to get the names of the activities'''
  activity = input("Enter the name of your {0} activity: ".format(list12l))
  while len(activity) > 10:
    print("Enter a name under 10 characters long")
    activity = input("Enter the name of your {0} activity: ".format(list12l))
  return activity

def get_pricing():
  '''this is the function that gets the hourly price for each activity'''
  validPrice = "a"
  while validPrice == 'a':
    price = float(input("Enter the hourly charge for this activity: "))
    if price > 5.99 or price < 0.99:
      print("This is an invalid price. Enter a valid price.")
    else:
      validPrice = "b"
  return price

def get_costs():
  table = []
  header = ['Activity, Charge per hour']
  table.append(header)
  list12l = ['first','second','last'] 
  for x in range(0,3): 
      across = []
      m = get_activityName(list12l[x])
      n = get_pricing()
      across.append(m)
      across.append(n)
      table.append(across)
  return table

def printFinalTable(table):
  for x,y in table:
    print("\t{0}".format(x,y))

def main():
    """runs all functions"""
    table = get_costs()
    print('\n')
    printFinalTable(table)
main()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to show *in the question*

Comment: This is a debugging question, which generally aren't allowed on stackoverflow. It means that you're trying to do `for x,y in table:
    print("\t{0}".format(x,y))` but at least one element of `table` has only one element, not two. Debug by doing `print(table)` just before this line (line 45).

Comment: `table` is a list of lists: `[['Activity, Charge per hour'], ['t', 1.0], ['g', 2.0], ['q', 3.0]]`

Comment: `header = ['Activity, Charge per hour'];
  table.append(header)` -- this is the issue. I'm guessing you mean `header = ['Activity', 'Charge per hour']`.

Comment: As for your error, Python will tell you *exactly* where it happens, on which line in the code. It's very hard for us to find it by just reading your code, so please edit your question to tell us which line it is (for example by adding a comment on that line). Also we really need to see the full and complete error, copy-pasted as text.

Comment: I'm sorry for all of the ambiguity in my question, and will keep all the points mentioned when I next post a question. Thank you also for finding the error. I will remember that debugging questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow next time. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your header is causing the issue.  It should be this.

```
header = ['Activity', 'Charge per hour']
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. It has helped me a lot.